# How to replicate viewport ghosting effect in renders (eevee)

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

When I play this animation in the viewport it has noisy motion blur/ghosting yet when I render it it the effect goes away despite using the same number of samples and using eevee.

Viewport:
https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExdjl2bGJpeGt3OHEzM2dsNzY3aWQwcGoydjVob240MzZjN3IyeDUwciZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/RUmQNcgBKgiI3O5E9U/giphy-downsized-large.gif

Render:
https://media.giphy.com/media/GE5qVhGZhwPAYZHWCK/giphy.gif

Any ideas on how to get the render to look more like the viewport?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Maybe render first frame normally, and after that render with some % opacity on top of the previous render?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady How can I do that in a timely fashion? Is that something you can do in the compositor?